# Hide React component without unmounting

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to effectively create a tabbed view where the content of each tab is only fetched when you click on the tab. I've implemented this by using a set of buttons as headers which update a `currentTab` value in the container's state and a switch which only renders a component based on that `currentTab` value. I then fetch the data in the `componentDidMount` function, achieving my intent of loading when the tab is actually selected.

The problem is that I don't want to have to load the data each time the tab is selected. Only the first time. I want the data in those components to remain when I click back so they don't have to be fetched again. I've already tried keeping references to each tab component within the container component and reusing those but that hasn't worked. That looked roughly like this:

```
class MyContainer extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {activeTab: this.props.initialTab}
        this.tabs = {
            'Actions': null,
            'Drawsheet': null,
            'Players': null,
            'About': null,
            'Contact': null
        };
    }

    getTab(){
        const tab = this.state.activeTab;
        if(this.tabs[tab] != null){
            return this.tabs[tab];
        }
        else {
            let newTab;
            switch (tab){
                case 'Actions':
                    newTab = <ActionsTab user={this.props.user}/>;
                    break;
                case 'Drawsheet':
                    newTab = <DrawsheetTab event={this.props.event}/>;
                    break;
                case 'Players':
                    newTab = <PlayersTab event={this.props.event}/>;
                    break;
                case 'About':
                    newTab = <AboutTab event={this.props.event}/>;
                    break;
                case 'Contact':
                    newTab = <ContactTab event={this.props.event}/>;
                    break;
            }
            this.tabs[tab] = newTab;
            return newTab;
        }
    }
    render(){
        let content = this.getTab();
        return(content);
}
```

This approach does still renders fine and everything but its remounting each time I render a component instead of retaining its status when I keep and reuse the reference to it.

What is the best way for me to go about hiding the already created tabs without unmounting them? Clearly keeping a reference while they are not being rendered isn't enough, I assume I have to render them all but just use a `display: none` or something like that? I've been reading in other posts however that will cause it to remount though, and using `visibility` would make them still take up space while hidden which isn't acceptable either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up coming up with my own solution based on @Diceros answer. Posting for anyone stumbling on this thread.

I added a `tabData` array to the container state, and then made a `saveTabData` function which I passed to each component as `onLoadData` and passed the data itself to the component as well.

In each tab component, instead of calling `this.setState` to save the data from the fetch, I call the callback `this.props.onLoadData` to save the data to the containers `tabData` array.
Then I refactored the render methods of each component to get the data from `this.props` instead of `this.state` and to simply display "Loading..." when the props data is null (ie. when it hasn't loaded yet).

Answer (score 1):

At the first place, I would move the whole switch with the tab components to the render and then I would use the `componentDidUpdate` and check if the active tab has been changed and if so, store the new tab to some kind of collection in state (below I used `opennedTabs`), where you will be collecting all of the previously openned tabs, and if the tab was not yet openned, fetch the data. If it was previously openned, do not fetch the data again. Using this way, you do not need to take care about the rendering and unmounting of the tabs and just handle the data properly.

In code:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    let opennedTabs = [...this.state.opennedTabs];
    if (prevState.activeTab !== this.state.activeTab) {
        if (opennedTabs?.length > 0 && !opennedTabs.includes(this.state.activeTab)) {
            //Fetch the data for this.state.activeTab
            opennedTabs.push(activeTab);
            this.setState({ opennedTabs });
        }
    }
}

render() {
            switch (this.state.activeTab){
                    case 'Actions':
                        return <ActionsTab fetchedData={dataActionsTab} user={this.props.user}/>;
                    case 'Drawsheet':
                        return <DrawsheetTab fetchedData={dataDrawsheetTab} event={this.props.event}/>;
                    case 'Players':
                        return <PlayersTab fetchedData={dataPlayersTab} event={this.props.event}/>;
                    case 'About':
                        return <AboutTab fetchedData={dataAboutTab} event={this.props.event}/>;
                    case 'Contact':
                        return <ContactTab fetchedData={dataContactTab} event={this.props.event}/>;
}
```

Comment: `opennedTabs.push(activeTab);`
Where is this activeTab variable coming from? Is that supposed to be the component itself or the string key? If the component, where should I be storing it and setting it?

Comment: The activeTab should be used to store the unique identifier of the currently clicked/default tab. Later this can be used to check if the tab is openned or not. Basically I get this from your example.